# Problems with FormData on mobile when uploading documents

Tags: react-native, http-post, form-data, joi

I have a React Native app, and I have ran into an issue when uploading documents.

I handle document uploads in various places throughout the app, and have not had this issue before.

A user can upload multiple documents in a form, and when they submit that, I iterate through the array of documents, and call my `POST` request method to send these to the backend server.

The code for sending the request is as follows:

```
  ...
  const formData = new FormData()
  // documentType is an identifier assigned to the document based on which field it is attributed to in the form
  formData.append('documentType', documentType)

  console.warn(formData)
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    // Web specific code
    // Working
  } else {
    formData.append('filesToUpload', {
      uri: documentURI,
      type: `image/${fileType}`,
      name: `${fileName}`,
    })
  }

  await fetch(
    new Request(<URL_ROUTE>,
      {
        method: 'POST',
      }
    ),
    {
      body: formData,
      headers,
    }
  ).then(...)
  ...
```

So the issue is, if more than one document/image are uploaded to the form, and submitted, in my endpoint, I get an error `error: ValidationError: "documentType" is required`.

I use `Joi` validation in my endpoints, I just can't workout what is going wrong.

If a single document is submitted, no issue, if multiple, then the first document is uploaded, but the subsequent documents throw that error.

I have checked in my React Native app that `documentType` has a value, and it does every time.

I appreciate this may not be enough code to go off, if so, let me know and I will try to provide more.